# SSAS MDX Rolling Total Different Date Ranges

Tags: sql, ssas, mdx, cube

I am working on a finance cube with a calculated member using the following `MDX` formula:

```
IIF
 (
  [Chart Of Accounts].[Account Sub Group].CurrentMember 
   = 
  [Chart Of Accounts].[Account Sub Group].&[RESULT-CURRENT YEAR], 
  [Measures].[Amount GL YTD], 
  SUM
     (
      ParallelPeriod
                    (
                     [Date].[Year -  Quarter -  Month -  Date].[Year],
                     100,
                     [Date].[Year -  Quarter -  Month -  Date].CurrentMember
                    )
      :
      [Date].[Year -  Quarter -  Month -  Date].CurrentMember,
      [Measures].[Amount GL]
     )
 )
```

All works as expected. `[RESULTS-CURRENT YEAR]` displays the correct total for YTD while every other entry displays the totals from beginning of time. Except for the Equity rollup which `[RESULTS-CURRENT YEAR]` is in. It adds the totals from the beginning of time as well which is inflating the Total Equity on my pivot table.

Any ideas on how I can correct this?

[Explanation Summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72G27.png)

Comment: `Except for the Equity rollup which [RESULTS-CURRENT YEAR] is in.` request you to throw some more light on this..

Comment: I've linked an image in the original post.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand the question but one thing I notice is that you have used `=` but to signal equality of members in `mdx` you should use `IS`

```
IIF
 (
  [Chart Of Accounts].[Account Sub Group].CurrentMember 
   IS
  [Chart Of Accounts].[Account Sub Group].&[RESULT-CURRENT YEAR], 
  [Measures].[Amount GL YTD], 
  SUM
     (
      ParallelPeriod
                    (
                     [Date].[Year -  Quarter -  Month -  Date].[Year],
                     100,
                     [Date].[Year -  Quarter -  Month -  Date].CurrentMember
                    )
      :
      [Date].[Year -  Quarter -  Month -  Date].CurrentMember,
      [Measures].[Amount GL]
     )
 )
```

To track down what is happening try adding these measures into your cube and then put them in the columns next to the troublesome column. What values do they return?.I suspect it might not return what you expect:

```
[Measures].[exploratory] AS
    [Date].[Year -  Quarter -  Month -  Date].CurrentMember.member_caption
[Measures].[exploratory2] AS
    [Chart Of Accounts].[Account Sub Group].CurrentMember.member_caption
```

Also I'm wondering if rather than going back 100 years maybe you could simplify by using `null`:

```
IIF
 (
  [Chart Of Accounts].[Account Sub Group].CurrentMember 
   IS
  [Chart Of Accounts].[Account Sub Group].&[RESULT-CURRENT YEAR], 
  [Measures].[Amount GL YTD], 
  SUM
     (
      NULL:[Date].[Year -  Quarter -  Month -  Date].CurrentMember,
      [Measures].[Amount GL]
     )
 )
```

---

***Edit***

I suspect that on the Grand Total row the currentmember of the hierarchy `[Chart Of Accounts].[Account Sub Group]` is the `[All]` member so the boolean condition of the iif is false. You could try amending to this:

```
IIF
 (
  (
   [Chart Of Accounts].[Account Sub Group].CurrentMember 
   IS [Chart Of Accounts].[Account Sub Group].&[RESULT-CURRENT YEAR]
  )
  OR
  (
   [Chart Of Accounts].[Account Sub Group].CurrentMember 
   IS [Chart Of Accounts].[Account Sub Group].[All]
  ) 
  ,[Measures].[Amount GL YTD] 
  ,SUM
     (
      NULL:[Date].[Year -  Quarter -  Month -  Date].CurrentMember,
      [Measures].[Amount GL]
     )
 )
```

Comment: I appreciate the insight. The expression you wrote does produce the same results in a more simplified way. The issue I'm still experiencing is that [RESULTS-CURRENT YEAR] is displaying properly in the Pivot Table with the summation of [Amount GL YTD] however, the Grand Total line for Total Equity in the Pivot Table is summing [RESULTS-CURRENT YEAR] from the beginning of time with [Amount GL]. The link to the image I had in my original post should replicate this visually.

Comment: Essentially, the line item detail is correct in my Excel Pivot Table but the grand total is incorrect. The Grand Total line is always defaulting to the false part of the IIF statement. When you manually sum up the item details you get the correct sum total.

Comment: The `IIF` will definitely be False for the Grand Total because the boolean condition of the `IIF` will be False. I've added a second exploratory measure to my answer - add these to your cube - then add the measures into the pivot to inspect what the currentmember's are returning. Then amend your measure accordingly.

Comment: Using the edited MDX formula I got the correct Line Details and Grand Totals for Total Equity. However, the Grand Total for the other [Account Sub Group] are from [Amount GL YTD] rather from the beginning of time. Also, the exploratory measure I added shows the Line Details with the appropriate [Account Sub Group] but the Total lines show the [All] member. Again, I need the Grand Total line to sum [Amount GL YTD] for [RESULTS-CURRENT YEAR] with SUM(NULL:[Date].[Year -  Quarter -  Month -  Date].CurrentMember,[Measures].[Amount GL]) which is the beginning of time formula.

Comment: @user3652818 did the new calculation fix the original problem?

Comment: No, It did not. The original problem is that the Grand Total line in the Pivot Table is always taking the false part of the IIF statement and not summing up the Line Details. I need it to sum up one Line Detail for the [Amount GL YTD] plus the amounts from the beginning of time.